# How to determine (cross-browser) if anything is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

How to determine (cross-browser) if anything is selected (in the current text field)? I need only a `true` or `false`. I've found [jQuery.selection](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/) but it's overloaded for my usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.getSelection().toString()` should work for you - supported by all browsers and IE7+

**EDIT:** I'm surprised this doesn't work for input elements. However there are `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties mentioned at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement so you can use them instead.

```
console.log(!!(el.selectionStart - el.selectionEnd));
// where el = your input element, like el = $('input')[0]
```

One minor glitch though, I found that these values do not change if you blur the input after selecting text, so I'll make use of `querySelector` to find if the input element has focus or not:

```
document.querySelector('#input:focus') //returns first matched element or null
```

Comment: @ThomasZuberbühler yeah indeed it doesn't work for input or textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most reliable (I guess) is to take code from jQuery.selection plugin. You will need only this function:

```
    var _getCaretInfo = function(element){
    var res = {
        text: '',
        start: 0,
        end: 0
    };

    if (!element.value) {
        /* 値がない、もしくは空文字列 */
        return res;
    }

    try {
        if (win.getSelection) {
            /* IE 以外 */
            res.start = element.selectionStart;
            res.end = element.selectionEnd;
            res.text = element.value.slice(res.start, res.end);
        } else if (doc.selection) {
            /* for IE */
            element.focus();

            var range = doc.selection.createRange(),
                range2 = doc.body.createTextRange(),
                tmpLength;

            res.text = range.text;

            try {
                range2.moveToElementText(element);
                range2.setEndPoint('StartToStart', range);
            } catch (e) {
                range2 = element.createTextRange();
                range2.setEndPoint('StartToStart', range);
            }

            res.start = element.value.length - range2.text.length;
            res.end = res.start + range.text.length;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        /* あきらめる */
    }

    return res;
};
```

If IE8< support not required - `if (doc.selection) {` section could be removed.

To get Boolean from this function, just replace `return res;` with `return !!res.text;`